# kernel build failed due to .config

Tags: android, build, arm, kernel

I'm trying to build an Android kernel for the arm architecture, but it fails all the time and it gives me this error:

```
 Using /home/build/tommolini_android/omap-android-kernel as source for kernel
  /home/build/tommolini_android/omap-android-kernel is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'
  in the '/home/build/tommolini_android/omap-android-kernel' directory.
make[1]: *** [prepare3] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
make[1]: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

If I run make mrproper inside that directory and do again make ARCH=arm -j8 it says that it doesn't find .config file:

```
***
*** Configuration file ".config" not found!
***
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
***
make[3]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

The commands I execute are:

```
make ARCH=arm distclean
make ARCH=arm platformX4_defconfig
make ARCH=arm -j8
```

How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: are you using windows /linux?

Comment: linux, Ubuntu is my os

Comment: Remove your .config file from your root directory. That's normally what will cause that error. You need a clean unmodified file tree.

Comment: by root directory you mean tha AOSP directory or the kernel one? Beacause if I remove the second one it tells me that it cannot find a .config file...

Comment: See this link it will helpful to you or not?  [link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/make-errors-when-building-from-kernel-source-3-10-7-in-seperate-output-directory-4175521996/)

Answer (score 0):

- take backup of .config or full kernel folder. run this to clean "make mrproper".
- then reconfigure with this command "make menuconfig" save
  and come out.
- now run "make" then do android build.

  A) tools/bazel clean --expunge
  B) tools/bazel build //common:kernel_aarch64_dist